# Cannot extend div height when hidden divs within are made visible

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I have a `<div>` that contains another `<div>`, which in turn contains a series of `<div>`s, which can be toggled. I have set the first two `<div>`s to have `height: 100%;`. So now when I have too many `<div>`s made visible and it does not fit into the screen, the main `<div>` does not extend, leaving the bg to be the color of body.

Here's how the (simplified) `html` looks like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col" id="col1"></div>
    <div class="col" id="col2"></div>
    <div class="col" id="col3"></div>
</div>
```

And the relevant `CSS`:

```
body, html {
    background-color: darkgray;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0;      
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    min-width: 722px;
    max-width: 1119px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
}

.col {
    /*background-color: red;*/
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0.6667%;
    margin-left: 0.6667%;
}

#col1 {
    width: 24%;
}

#col2 {
    width: 48%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}

#col3 {
    width: 24%;
}
```

This is how it looks like in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sodiumnitrate/HbjtG/1/).

And here's a screenshot of the problem:
[image: screenshot of the problem]
I have tried to add the following code to the `jQuery` (within the `.click` function) to solve the problem:

```
var top = $('#col2:last-child').position().top;

var bottom = top + $('#col2:last-child').height();
$('#wrapper').css('height', bottom);
```

which, in chrome, gives me the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

I really would like to solve this within `CSS` if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add `overflow:auto;` to that `#wrapper`. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbjtG/3/)

Either that, or clear your `div`'s

Edit: And you can set that `#wrapper` into `height:auto;` if you want to make it wrap the whole text, instead of being scrollable. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HbjtG/2/)

Comment: Ok, I don't want it to be scrollable, but `height:auto;` makes the dark gray color of the `div` to vanish. I get the lighter gray bg.

Comment: Did you set `overflow:auto;` to `#wrapper` as well, or just `height:auto;`? Check the second fiddle on my answer, you should see a working scenario.

Comment: Ok, It does work that way. But there are two things that I lose when I do that. I'm about to lose my mind, I cannot get these three things to work. I also want to give a `min-height:100%;` to `#wrapper` so that I have no light gray bg showing at the bottom. Also, I want there to be a full height `#col2` so that when the `div`s within it are hidden with `jQuery`, I still have a `box-shadow` that extends to the bottom of the page, like the darkgray background.

Comment: I dont think that will be possible. Unless you want to have the actual `#wrapper` scrollable. In order to do what you want, you MUST set an explicit height for `#wrapper`. Unless you want to do something like `#col2 { min-height: 600px; }`. That would work, but wouldnt be very "dynamic-like"

Comment: Since you already have jQuery there, you could possibly use something like `$('#col2').css('min-height', window.innerHeight-30);` to achieve what you want. This should do it. http://jsfiddle.net/HbjtG/6/

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display: inline-block;` rather than `float: left;` personal preference I suppose, but when possible I try to avoid messing with the document flow (which can cause problems like what you're seeing).

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HbjtG/5/)**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
    min-width: 722px;
    max-width: 1119px;
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
}
.col {
    width: 24%;
    /*background-color: red;*/
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#col2 {
    width: 48%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}
p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
img {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5%;
}
ul {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: -5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
#col2 h1 {
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 6px black;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#col2 ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left:-2.5%;
}
.col em {
    color:#000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.col em:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#homepageButton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #444;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
#homepageButton a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 6px black;
}
#homepageButton a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
* {
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to everything... see: [Paul Irish's explanation for that](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: I also added `min-height: 100%;`, which achieved exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/sodiumnitrate/HbjtG/1/

I added a `.clearfix` to your wrapper, and I forced the wrapper to full height, to make it take up at least the entire viewport, but grow if the content requires it.

```
/* clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* IE < 8 */
}

#wrapper {
  /* force full height */
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;    
  ...
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it properly. Content in 2nd `.researchContent` overflows the `div` and `#wrapper`. You need more clearing done.